# Power BI DAX: Carry-over category status from latest date for every calendar month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have been trying various methods and experiencing shortcomings in carrying over Latest-status of a category independent to Calendar date .. hence this request.

I have a Category Table as below:

[image]

I am trying to group CategoryID & Last(TestDate) by every month and obtain status of every Category monthly; wherever there doesn't exist test date, use the Category Status value available for that category from Latest Test Date.

Such as below:

[image]

Things I tried to achieve:

1. Summarizing category Table
2. Add Calendar Table
3. Try obtaining the Latest status - yet no luck..

I tried something to achieve max-date but, falls flat!

```
Latest = VAR maxdate = MAX(Category[Test Date])
VAR cat = SELECTEDVALUE(Category[TestID]) 
RETURN
CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE(Categoty[Category Status]),Categrory[Test ID] = Cat, FILTER(Category,Category[Testdate]=maxdate))
```

Any advise appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your current dataset with add column for MM-YYYY:

[image]

And you already create one calendar table for rolling status even the month is not show in the dataset:

[image]

First, you need to create the MM-YYYY in the calendar table again (assume you already know how to do it), then you will use combination of `Lookup & calculate` to return the rolling status as per your expectation (your dataset must have unique category name for each month):

```
Status = 
var result = LOOKUPVALUE(Sheet1[Category Status],Sheet1[MM-YYYY],
                'Calendar'[MM-YYYY],Sheet1[Category Name],'Calendar'[Category])
return
IF(ISBLANK(result),CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK(Sheet1[Category Status],1),
    FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Category Name]=EARLIER('Calendar'[Category])),
        FILTER(Sheet1, Sheet1[Test Date] <= EARLIER('Calendar'[Calendar Month]))), result)
```

Here is the final output (it is interesting to see that `FirstNonBlank` return correct output rather than `LastNonBlank`) with Jul, Aug and Oct are using rolling status from latest available month:

[image]

Comment: I want the  grouping table on a rollover calendar date.. any advise appreciated.

Comment: It is group by rollover month, because i only use you example for calculation, therefore it only show Jan2020 & Jan2021, please try and see the output.

Comment: I am not able to show on a rolling calendar date. I tried joining Calendar Date to MM-YYYY but, no luck.

Comment: I am using `format([date],"mmm") & "-" & year([date])` to get the MM-YYYY, you obtain it from excel only?

Comment: Kin, I have managed to create it using Format. However, when I am place it in a calendar, I only see values on Test Date instead of group by category and Month and rollover to next month too

Comment: can you please show some image for what is the actual problem, I can't really understand the problem here...

Comment: Updated the query above. please check.

Comment: ok, it seem like it not a grouping issue because you are trying to give a status for the category even there is not value for the respective month. In such case, you need add value for Jul & Aug in excel as PowerBi is not able to create data out of nowhere....

Comment: Agreed, Kin. Henceforth I have created a Calendar Table and trying to group by calendar month to achieve the same.

Comment: You may see my edited answer, last try for me :)

Comment: Kin, can you suggest how to generate: "And you already create one calendar table for rolling status even the month is not show in the dataset" ? I am using standard Calendar() Table without any category name column. I joined Calendar date with Test Date in Category table. Your suggesting is a bit new here. Are you suggesting me create a new calendar table with possibly a date every month for every category id?

Comment: The calendar month table with ID is manually created by me.